# Why does Database.SqlQuery terminate the transaction I started with Database.BeginTransaction?

Tags: transactions, entity-framework-6

This is unbelievable. I'm using EF6, and I'm calling `Database.BeginTransaction`, which is the "recommended" way to start a transaction.  I then call `Database.SqlQuery<T>` to call a stored procedure that makes some modifications and then returns some data. After this call, the Database.CurrentTransaction is null. It wiped it out. Why does it do that?

I am of course storing the DbContextTransaction returned by BeginTransaction, and when I call "Commit" on it, I get an error saying the underlying provider failed on commit, and that the connection is null. I presume that happens as a result of SqlQuery wiping out the CurrentTransaction. It makes no sense.

Comment: Database.SqlQuery is auto-committing a transaction started with Database.BeginTransaction. This makes no sense.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it will be hard to determine what might be happening. For instance, Is this all within the scope of a single method?